# Socket.IO, multiple connections on page load

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have a socketIO/express app that goes like this :

```
function joinRoom(socket,roomName){
    socket.join(roomName);
    console.log('success joining '+roomName);
    socket.broadcast.to(roomName).emit('chat',{type:'join',msg:guestList[socket.id]+' has arrived in '+roomName+'!'});
    socket.emit('chat',{type:'join',msg:'You are now in '+roomName});
}

function assignName(socket){
    var name = 'Player#'+guestId;
    guestList[socket.id]= name;
    socket.emit('chat',{type:'name',msg:name});
    return guestId+1;
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  io.of('/lobby').on('connection', function (socket) {
    guestId=assignName(socket);             
    joinRoom(socket, 'Lobby');      
  });   
  handleMessage(socket);
});
```

When I open a first browser window, everything goes well, I see Player#0 connected, and the join room msg. However, when I open a second window or browser, I see 2 connections (player#1 and #2), then if I open a 3rd window, i will see 3 connections, #3,#4,#5. What the heck? It has to be something stupid but I can't figure it out, Help!

G.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted!
Basically, I separated the namespace connection from the io.sockets.on(...) and behaviour went back to normal. It makes sense, although I'm not sure why the number of connect events was incremental...